# Adapt two elements to the smartphone screen

Tags: html, css

I have some html and css like below. I want to adaptive it for mobile screen.
And add to block of Sites Google.

When I add `width: 100%` for `container` and `form__field` I gave:

**Site Google**

[image]

**Only code**, without site Google

[image]

If remove `width: 100%` looks like this. That's correct.

[image]

If insert on the website Google something already adapted for mobile devices - it is displayed correctly. Properly scaled.

```css
:root {
  background: #f5f6fa;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  font: 1rem "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7f8ff4;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.padding_p{
  padding-left: 18px
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 9px
}
.btn--primary {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #6c7ff2;
}
.btn--back--primary:hover {
  background: #9c9c9c2d;
}
.btn--primary:active {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.btn--inside {
  margin-left: -96px;
}

.form__field {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 22px 114px 22px 18px;
}

.form__textarea {
  width: 440px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 18px 18px;
  margin: 18px;
  resize: none;
}

.box div { 
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-block; 

}

@media (max-width: 400){

  .container{
    width: 100%
  }

  .form__field{
    width: 100%
  }

  .btn{
    width: 100%
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form" action="/submit" method="POST">
            <input name="playlist_url" type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Ссылка на плейлист" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--inside uppercase">Загрузить</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**

According [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511738/5894542). Can I change the scale? Otherwise, it turns out that it is cut.

[image]

Here's what it looks like without embedding on the site. Can you make it full width?

[image]

Comment: What is the connection to Google here? _“And add to block of Sites Google”_, _“Only code, without site Google”_ - no clue what you are talking about here.

Comment: @misorude I mean https://sites.google.com/ and `embedded code` (block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add first or second snippet.

```
/************* short way **************/
form {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.form__field {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/************* better way **************/
.btn--inside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.form__field {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90%;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've made edits in the answer. (second code snippet)